# Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

Tags: android, logging, logcat

i'm using avd android 4.2 armeabi-v7a 
I want using logcat. but avd is not have /dev/log
what can i do..

OS : Apple M2 pro Ventura 13.2.1z
Emulator : Andorid Studio 2022.1.1 - avd(android 4.2 armeabi-v7a)

- android 4.1 armabi-v7a has /dev/log/main
- android 5.0 armabi-v7a has /dev/log/main

**I tried..**

1. dial *#*#2846579#*#* - not work.
2. $logcat-enable - system/bin/sh: logcat-enable: not found.
3. install semaphore manager apk - No root access! ..
4. adb reboot bootloader - avd can't use fastboot
5. $insmod /system/lib/modules/logger.ko - not found /system/lib/modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue with my M2 Pro.
If the problem was only logcat, it was solved with [Rev.5](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/armeabi-v7a-17_r05.zip) system image

However, there is a problem that the system clock cannot be set in both Rev.5 and Rev.6, and it has not been completely resolved.
Unfortunately, I can't find the system image before Rev.4 and can't try it.